# what is a stored procedure and in what sense its differenct than a simple one?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to know what is a difference between a "stored procedure" and a simple one. Are stored procedures built-in?

Comment: What do you mean by "a simple procedure"?

Comment: I guess you could contrast it to a) a built-in function/procedure and b) an ad-hoc block of code

Comment: simple procedure :- the one user creates

Comment: "A procedure that a user creates" is pretty much the definition of "stored procedure". (if by "create" you mean "create inside of the database" and not "define in a client-side program")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure is nothing more than prepared SQL code that you save so you can reuse the code over and over again.  So if you think about a query that you write over and over again, instead of having to write that query each time you would save it as a stored procedure and then just call the stored procedure to execute the SQL code that you saved as part of the stored procedure.

In addition to running the same SQL code over and over again you also have the ability to pass parameters to the stored procedure, so depending on what the need is the stored procedure can act accordingly based on the parameter values that were passed.

Benefits of Using the Stored Procedure

1. One of the main benefits of using the Stored procedure is that it reduces the amount of information sent to the database server. It can become a more important benefit when the bandwidth of the network is less. Since if we send the SQL query (statement) which is executing in a loop to the server through network and the network gets disconnected, then the execution of the SQL statement doesn't return the expected results, if the SQL query is not used between Transaction statement and rollback statement is not used.
2. Compilation step is required only once when the stored procedure is created. Then after it does not require recompilation before executing unless it is modified and reutilizes the same execution plan whereas the SQL statements need to be compiled every time whenever it is sent for execution even if we send the same SQL statement every time.
3. It helps in re usability of the SQL code because it can be used by multiple users and by multiple clients since we need to just call the stored procedure instead of writing the same SQL statement every time. It helps in reducing the development time.
4. Stored procedure is helpful in enhancing the security since we can grant permission to the user for executing the Stored procedure instead of giving permission on the tables used in the Stored procedure.
5. Sometimes, it is useful to use the database for storing the business logic in the form of stored procedure since it makes it secure and if any change is needed in the business logic, then we may only need to make changes in the stored procedure and not in the files contained on the web server.

For more info check [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-To-Write-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL) & [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/)